# How to make a sort array and count array button?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to create a code that sorts products into alphabetical order and then count the number of them for class. I know how to create a program that does one or the other, but when I try to put them both in it doesn't work, I've tried to change the code around but i still can't find a way for this to work, so I must be doing something wrong. Any help would be really appreciated. Here is the current code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <p>Printer, Tablet, Router, Computer, Phone.</p>

    <p>Click the button to sort the products into Alphabetical Order.</p>

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>
        var products = ["Printer", "Tablet", "Router", "Computer","Phone"];
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = products;

        function myFunction() {
            products.sort();
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = products;
        }
    </script>

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Count the Number of Products!</button>

    <p id="demo2"></p>

    <script>
        var products = ["Printer", "Tablet", "Router", "Computer","Phone"];
        prod1=products.count();

        function myFunction() {
            products.length();
            document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = products;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A little [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) would make this a lot simpler. A little [Lodash](http://lodash.com/) wouldn't hurt either. Note that `count()` is not a method on array, and `length` is a property, not a method. As always, keep the [documentation on Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) open if you're ever uncertain.

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Are you seeing any errors?

Comment: @tadman OP is a beginner, so I don't think jQuery is recommended.

Comment: Though, just glancing at your code, I noticed you define `myFunction` twice. That is likely your problem.

Comment: @tadman I disagree. jQuery introduces a series of complex concepts like advanced DOM manipulation, callbacks, hooks. Those will surely confuse a beginner. Since OP is doing his/her first steps, it is best to learn pure Javascript, then learn how jQuery expands upon it. Obviously, `$('#demo').html('...')` makes more sense, but only to a seasoned developer, and the focus here is not just to solve the problem, but also to learn valuable concepts in the process.

Comment: I've deleted all my comments in an attempt to clean up this question. jQuery allows you to focus on getting things done and promotes modern, readable JavaScript. Preaching fundamentals is fine, but there literally is no bottom to that. There's a problem to be solved here. jQuery solves it neatly. JavaScript requires a lot more cognitive overhead for a beginner.

Comment: @tadman Well, I had to delete mine too then. My point was only to preserve OP's learning experience by keeping it to the fundamentals and without introducing a new library (jQuery) in the mix. I won't comment anymore. Maybe we should discuss this over a beer, since we live in the same city :)

Comment: Yeah! Check out [DevTO](http://www.devto.ca/) for stuff like that. I'd encourage any developer looking to get a head-start to find groups like that to share knowledge with.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to programming! It is fun, except when it's not. But it gets fun again right after you solve your problem :)

The problem with your code is, even if you separate your code inside two `<script>` tags, it will still be read by the browser as a single program. In your case, notice that it will make you have two functions with the same name and two 'Products' arrays, and the second one will overwrite the first one.

Answer (score 1):

There were a number of problems with your code. The first is that scripts should be in a separate script file. You also created two functions with the same name. There was also a problem with this function

```
function myFunction() {
    products.length();
    document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = products;
}
```

First of all `length()` is not a JavaScript function, it should be `length`. And second, you are not storing the length of the array in a variable. You are storing the products array.

Also `array.count()` is not a function either. You are also reusing the same code in both of your scripts block. Either place them in an external script file, or only use one script block. And change the name of your functions.

Here is my solution

```
var products = ["Printer", "Tablet", "Router", "Computer","Phone"];
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = products;

var buttonOne = document.getElementById("buttonOne");
var buttonTwo = document.getElementById("buttonTwo");

buttonOne.addEventListener("click", function() {
    products = products.sort();
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = products;
});

buttonTwo.addEventListener("click", function() {
    length = products.length;
    document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = length;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9r08ucbu/1/